# Campaign plugin opinions

Tags: emails

I have a client who has 250k+ subscribers and is sending out 500k+ marketing emails per month.

Their marketing email provider is charging them a LOT.

I’m interested in setting them up with the Campaign plugin (https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/campaign) and sending through Amazon SES.

I’m sure they’d save a lot, but I’m wary of running a list this size through a plugin.

Does anyone have experience of Campaign on a list this size? (Or at all?)

Thanks

Comment: The one thing I’d add to the answers already provided is that the Campaign plugin can recover from issues during sendout. Still though, with such a large list it is highly recommended to run queue jobs via console commands (or better yet via a dedicated queue runner), see https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms for a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, we have the Async plugin installed which seemed to handle the contact import OK when we broke it down into multiple CSVs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A client of mine has been using Campaign for close to 5 years now and it's been pretty solid. His list is definitely smaller but it's running on multisite, sending recurring emails every week as well as manually scheduled ones during the week. Using Amazon SES, which is super cheap, bounces and complaints stats are send back to Campaign in Craft. Everything works great. I have set max batch to 300 which is fairly low. I am sure you can increase that without issues. It's running a relative small VPS and resources usage does climb a little bit but it has never broken the server or frontend during sendout.
Bottom line. Works great for me and with the queue system I would expect it would work fine for you too but I cannot promise though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

We use it all the time on various clients and it can handle whatever you throw at it in our experience.

With the queue system, it just churns away with the send until it's done. As Philip says, it handles bounces etc with ease. It gives you reports on clicks, opens etc. Also, Ben is a seriously good plugin developer and is incredibly responsive to issues if you have any.

We use Postmark as our ESP and have never had any issues. Very happy with it and can highly recommend both the plugin and Postmark!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I’ll give Postmark a look.

Answer (score 2):

Campaign is an excellent plugin, and Ben a truly excellent and supportive developer.

The approach is just superb - being able to edit in the CMS, and use existing content, is revelatory vs. the traditional approach in e.g. Mailchimp or similar.  Of course the developer has to do a bunch of work on email templates (ergh!) - to get the quality of content delivery to similar levels to what you get out of the box with a service.  Things like MJML or similar can greatly help ease that development of course.

The cost is *dramatically* cheaper than any service based alternative.  And the more you send, the more you save!

My only caveat to raise is with the sending performance side of things.  If you're used to Mailchimp or similar, you'll know the entire thing sends in the blink of any eye with those services - even to massive lists.  Indeed, with those, often you might want to slow things down and stagger delivery to prevent the inevitable server hit from all those folks clicking on your links etc., when you do a send out.

We have about 10000 on our list, use Postmark as our ESP (they are brilliant - best SAAS I've ever used!) - but the sending does take a fair while and place a noticeable amount of load on the server during that time.  That is of course inherent to the Campaign approach of using Craft templates and your server.  (Without any performance optimisation/caching, using MJML based templates, and using a $20 Vultr VPS, it's about 10+ hours to send to the list.  Not insignificant!).  With caching, this can be significantly improved but we have had some issues with stale previews etc when doing this, so don't feel we have things quite right yet.

Given the list size you're talking about, you'll definitely want to spend more time on the performance optimisation than most would normally need to do, do some extensive testing, and just be aware of this during your development.  But once you're using Campaign, you'll likely never want to go back to anything else, as the content/editing approach & experience is just so great.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)